# How to calculate shadow area for objects perpendicular to sunlight?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, geometric-optics

I'd like to know how it'd be possible to calculate the area of a shadow projected on the ground by an object perpendicular to sunlight and held at different heights.

I'd expect that at height H = 0, A(object)=A(shadow), however when height is going to increase A(object)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The sun's rays are effectively parallel by the time they reach the surface of the Earth so the size of the shadow is the same size as the object independent of its height above the ground.

What you do see is that the edges of the shadow become less sharp as the object moves farther from the ground.  This is because even at its great distance we still have to treat the Sun as an extended source rather than a point source.

I've you've hand a chance to observe the shadow of a bird or airplane on the ground you'll notice they are still the same size as the original object.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would the area ratios change if considering shadow as any area in which light does not hit the ground unaltered/unfiltered? At which distance could the areas ratio increase?